# Merge two lists objects

Tags: c#

i'm having a problem with merging two list of object
here they are:

```
first one
List<NSKData> NSKDataList = new List<NSKData>();

public class NSKData
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Issue { get; set; }
    public string ToolTipInfoText { get; set; }
    public NSKData() { }
    public NSKData(string id, string issue, string tooltipinfo)
    {
        ID = id;
        Issue= issue;
        ToolTipInfoText = tooltipinfo;
    }
}

 second one
 List<IssuesMoreInfo> IssuesMoreInfoList = new List<IssuesMoreInfo>();

public class IssuesMoreInfo
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string IssueMoreInfoText { get; set; }
}
```

If i can get all needed data at one time, i wont ask this question, but i'm grabbing all data for fist one, and only after i can get data for second one.

So, what i need in result is:
to get IssueMoreInfo from second one, according to ID in both, like for id 10 in first one, we getting IssueMoreInfoText column in second one and pass it to firt one list in column ToolTipInfoText

Hope for your help, guys, thanks

Comment: As it is, it's not clear, what exactly you want your output to look like. It might help if you could provide an example of your input and what the result should be.

Comment: im grabbing in from some bugtracker in internet, parse it, and after fill list with with data, is it important?                      

`foreach (var rowrow in NeededIssuesDataList)
            { 
                    NSKDataList.Add(new NSKData()
                    {
                        ID = rowrow.ID,
                        Issue= Issue
                        ToolTipInfo = "No info"
                    });
}`

Comment: are you getting this data db?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you're looking for `Enumerable.Join`:

```
var query = from data in NSKDataList 
            join info in IssuesMoreInfoList 
            on data.ID equals info.ID
            select new NSKData(data.ID, data.Issue, info.IssueMoreInfoText);
NSKDataList = query.ToList();
```

Another way which does not need to re-create all objects and the list:

```
var infoIdLookup = IssuesMoreInfoList.ToLookup(i => i.ID);
foreach(NSKData data in NSKDataList)
{
    data.ToolTipInfoText = infoIdLookup[data.ID]
       .Select(i => i.IssueMoreInfoText)
       .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using Linq Join

```
var query = from c in NSKDataList 
            join o in IssuesMoreInfoList on c.ID equals o.ID
            select new { c.ID, c.Issues , c.ToolTipInfoText , o.IssueMoreInfo  };
```

The query will contains info from both of the lists

http://www.dotnetperls.com/join

Answer (score 0):

To use Linq its easier to do:

```
NSKDataList.ForEach(nskData => nskData.ToolTipInfoText = IssuesMoreInfoList.Where(imf => imf.ID == nskData.ID).SingleOrDefault().IssueMoreInfoText);
```

What it does is:

Foreach element in `NSKDataList` it will change its `ToolTipInfoText` where you go to the `IssuesMoreInfoList` and filter it by `ID` as requested and then get the one returned or default (if none was selected) and get its `IssueMoreInfoText`.